# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'username'@'%' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, database, permissions, privileges, sql-grant

I Installed MySQL on my CentOS 6.4 server. I logged into my root and changed its password.

Later I thought that I should make a new user and use that user as my default user, So I created a new user name `golden` using the following command:

```
CREATE USER 'golden'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Then I applied permission to the user `golden`:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'golden'@'%';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Now this user: `golden` was able to do everything. So I finally `Deleted the root user`. Now I am stuck up on granting privilege to my one another new user.

I created another user, when I was logged in through `golden` (At this time I had already deleted the `root` user and command successfully created and the new user I am able to see it in list also)

```
CREATE USER 'fashion'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Then the following commands below gives me error:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'fashion'@'%';
```

**ERROR:** ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'golden'@'%' (using password: YES)

I also tried the following command the result is below:

```
mysql> SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();
+------------------+----------------+
| USER()           | CURRENT_USER() |
+------------------+----------------+
| golden@localhost | golden@%       |
+------------------+----------------+
```

If I wont be able to give access to this user then how can I login and use the database? Kindly help.

**EDIT 1: The following command gives me the following result**

```
mysql> select user, host FROM mysql.user;
+------------+-------+
| user       | host  |
+------------+-------+
| golden     | %     |
| fashion    | %     |
+------------+-------+
```

Comment: So total how many users exist in your mysql??

Comment: @Jhanvi I have done an edit, kindly check

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of, I can't imagine the reason why you've deleted `root` user. But back to the question - you should specify `WITH GRANT OPTION`, like this:

*(However this should be opted after you get the mysql re-installed as if you don't have the `root` access and the user is not having the sufficient privileges also, then the best is to restart the install process and make the user and grant them privileges the way defined below)*

```
mysql> create user 'golden'@'localhost' identified by 'password';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> grant all privileges on *.* to golden@localhost with grant option;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> flush privileges;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

and then

```
mysql> select current_user();
+------------------+
| current_user()   |
+------------------+
| golden@localhost |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> create database testing;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> grant all privileges on testing.* to test;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> drop database testing;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.12 sec)
```

-but yet again, think twice before deleting `root` user.

Comment: But now I am logged in as user `golden` only. So how can I execute this now?? Because I don't have `root`

Comment: Noway. Reinstalling your instance of MySQL server seems to be most easiest solution. That's why you should not do anything if you're not sure. `root` is normally a system user. It's possible to have configuration without it, but it's not recommended.

Comment: Ok I was hoping to do so. Anyways, thanks for your time and efforts. It looks the best to reinstall

Answer (score 2):

have you tried this?

```
update mysql.user set grant_priv='Y' where user='golden';
flush privileges;
```

and then quit and re-connect to the database as user golden.

Answer (score 0):

most easy way to solve this problem is--

1.go to control pannel and make hidden files and folders visible (if not done before)
2.now go to your c drive and open a hidden folder "program data" in it.
3.search mysql folder and delete it.
4.uninstall mysql 5.1.
5. reinstall it using wizard.
it will ask ur new password.. 
:) enjoy