# Error 1045 (28000) Access deneied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I am using ubuntu 16.04 and have just installed mysql. However, I am not able to access the mysql shell. I keep getting the Error 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Could you please help. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using a password?

Comment: Yes of course. That is , the mysql password with mysql -u root -p . But to no avail. The server is running, I checked this, but I cannot access the shell.

Comment: Did you try running `mysql_secure_installation`?

Comment: I still get the same error Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe hard resetting the password helps. Alot of people are getting this issue.

Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21685641/1863487

Comment: Unfortunately, among the instructions there is mysql -u root, which does not work for me : ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'

Comment: Then it probably isnt running. Can you try `sudo service mysqld start`?

Comment: [No more](https://askubuntu.com/a/793630/349837) `service`, [now is](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-linux-16-04/) `sudo systemctl restart mysql.service`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments. I solved the problem by reinstalling mysql from the mysql-api-config_0.3.8.1_all.deb file and can now access the mysql shell.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this helped:

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve problem like this :
add

`[mysqld]
skip-grant-tables`

to this file -->
`nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf'
then ---->`
mysql -u root
`set root password-->`
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('root'), plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root' AND Host='localhost';FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
`exit console`
\q
`comment edited file with # on start of line
restart mysql -->`
sudo service mysql restart
`and at last -->`
sudo mysql -u root -p`